# JS: ordinate access to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have a little problem, i thought how to resolve it but i don't know if it's the right way.

in my project I have several functions, all of which must use a sequential unique id every time a function is executed

for example:

```
person 1 runs function X using id 1
person 2 runs function Y using id 2
person 3 runs function Z using id 3
person 4 runs function Y using id 4
person 1 runs function Z using id 5
....
```

***how to do that?***

I thought to save that id **in a table inside mongoDB** and every time it will used inside a function, the function will increment it, but i don't think it is the right way, **it is?**

then, if it is the right way, how to co-ordinate the access to the DB?
like if 2 people runs 2 functions in the same time, the will take the same ID from DB and **this absolutely must not happen**, every time a function is called a **different id** must be used, how can I do?

Comment: Which version of Mongo DB you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Example:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name" : "function_trigger_count" },
   { $inc: { "count: 1 } }
)
```

FindOneAndUpdate ensure the atomicity of the query

**OR**

If you are using MongoDB version 5.x you can use [Transaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) feature to ensure the atomicity